# SQL - STDEVP or STDEV and how to use it?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stdevp, stdev

I have a table:

```
LocationId OriginalValue Mean
1          0.45         3.99  
2          0.33         3.99
3          16.74        3.99
4          3.31         3.99
```

and so forth...

How would I work out the `Standard Deviation` using this table and also what would you recommend - `STDEVP` or `STDEV`?

Comment: Are these the original data points and if so what is mean?

Comment: Mean is the overall average

Comment: Hmm they add up to more than 20 - so mean should be above 5

Comment: Sorry this is just a sample of the table not the entire table, shouldve mentioned that

Answer (score 50, accepted):

To use it, simply:

```
SELECT STDEVP(OriginalValue)
FROM yourTable
```

From below, you probably want `STDEVP`.

From [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/br/sqlanalysisservices/thread/0d8edea2-f08e-41b7-b120-8ac08855c23b):

> **STDEV** is used when the group of numbers being evaluated are only a **partial sampling** of the whole population. The denominator for dividing the sum of squared deviations is N-1, where N is the number of observations ( a count of items in the data set ). Technically, subtracting the 1 is referred to as "non-biased."
>
> **STDEVP** is used when the group of numbers being evaluated is complete - it's the **entire population** of values. In this case, the 1 is NOT subtracted and the denominator for dividing the sum of squared deviations is simply N itself, the number of observations ( a count of items in the data set ). Technically, this is referred to as "biased." Remembering that the P in STDEVP stands for "population" may be helpful. Since the data set is not a mere sample, but constituted of ALL the actual values, this standard deviation function can return a more precise result.

Comment: Explanation at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel%27s_correction#Source_of_bias

Comment: what is the default standard deviation 1, 2 or 3 in STDEV function?. can we change it?
68% of values are within 1 standard deviation of the mean
OR 95% of values are within 2 standard deviations of the mean
OR 99.7% of values are within 3 standard deviations of the mean

Comment: @AbubakarRiaz If you're calculating *the* standard deviation, that is 1 standard deviation by definition. This should be true for basically all functions that calculate standard deviation. If you want 2 or 3 standard deviations, you could just multiply the result by 2 or 3. Note that [the 68/95/99.7 rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68%E2%80%9395%E2%80%9399.7_rule) only applies for data with an approximately normal distribution.

Answer (score 13):

Generally, you should use `STDEV` when you have to estimate standard deviation based on a sample. But if you have entire column-data given as arguments, then use `STDEVP`.

> In general, if your data represents the entire population, use `STDEVP`; otherwise, use `STDEV`.

Note that for large samples, the functions return nearly the same value, so better use `STDEV` in this case.

Comment: My table contains about 240 rows, what option should I use? And what does it mean 'sample'?

Comment: as I had stated, it doesnt matter what you use, if u have large data (which is in your case).

Sample here means what type of data you have, {like 2.0, 3.0 or 2.4,3.4 like that!  }

Comment: In your last paragraph, you suggest using `STDEV` for large samples (even when the data represents the complete population and according to your answer, `STDEVP` would be more appropriate). Why?

Answer (score 8):

In statistics, there are two types of standard deviations: one for a sample and one for a population.

The **sample standard deviation**, generally notated by the letter s, is used as an estimate of the population standard deviation.

The **population standard deviation**, generally notated by the Greek letter lower case sigma, is used when the data constitutes the complete population.

It is difficult to answer your question directly -- sample or population -- because it is difficult to tell what you are working with: a sample or a population. It often depends on context.

Consider the following example.
If I want to know the standard deviation of the age of students in my class, then I u=would use STDEVP because the class is my population. But if I want the use my class as a sample of the population of all students in the school (this would be what is known as a convenience sample, and would likely be biased, but I digress), then I would use STDEV because my class is a sample. The resulting value would be my best estimate of STDEVP.

As mentioned above (1) for large sample sizes (say, more than thirty), the difference between the two becomes trivial, and (2) generally you should use STDEV, not STDEVP, because in practice we usually don't have access to the population. Indeed, one could argue that if we always had access to populations, then we wouldn't need statistics. The entire point of inferential statistics is to be able to make inferences about a population based on the sample.