# utilize c# formula in web pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, webmatrix

whats the easiest way to calculate the standard deviation of a query column  webmatrix? any predefined method, etc?

if there isn't any easy way.. how can i utilize this code?

```
public static double StandardDeviation(List<double> valueList)
{
double M = 0.0;
double S = 0.0;
int k = 1;
foreach (double value in valueList)
{
    double tmpM = M;
    M += (value - tmpM) / k;
    S += (value - tmpM) * (value - M);
    k++;
    }
    return Math.Sqrt(S / (k-2));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are getting your data from SQL Server, then letting the database do the calculations may work for you.  Something like

```
SELECT STDEVP(valueList)
FROM yourTable
```

or more specifically to WebMatrix

```
@{
   var sd = db.QueryValue( "SELECT STDEVP(valueList) FROM yourTable");
}

<p>
SD is @sd
</p>
```

See this question for more [SQL - STDEVP or STDEV and how to use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14893912/sql-stdevp-or-stdev-and-how-to-use-it)

Comment: dear knox.. STDEVP doesn't appear to be supported in webmatrix/sql Compact Edition.. anyway, I assume the best answer may be seen here:
http://forums.asp.net/p/2033343/5854905.aspx?p=True&t=635584667300135174